# How to append a list output to the columns in dataframe using for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a list containg 8 lists which contains marks , I have a dataframe in which my column names are student name and subject, I want to append these list to to columns, without mentioning columns names using for loop.

```
count_x=[[7, 3, 4, 4, 2, 41, 8],
    [3, 9, 0, 8, 2, 22, 11],
      [2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 9, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
      [2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 9],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
     [3, 2, 0, 8, 1, 10, 9]]
```

I tried using iloc but here i need to specify column names manually, I am not able to automate it for another dataframe.

`df1.iloc[:,5:13]=count_x`

`Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

but it gives me error like this, even though my keys and values are same.

I am expecting to automate append list values to dataframe using loop and also why iloc is not working in my condition, I run same code in another system, it worked fine.

Comment: what is `print(df.shape)`? Would something like `df1.iloc[:,5:5+len(count_x[0])] = count_x` work for you?

Comment: How looks original DataFrame and final ouput after append?

Comment: @cs95 df.shape = (7,14), df1.iloc[:,5:5+len(count_x[0])] = count_x its working but only 7 columns are getting filled, 8th column returns as blank.

Comment: `count_x` has 7 columns, that's why :)

Comment: @cs95 count_x has 8 lists, for 8 columns, dataframe should get filled vertically not horizontally. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If number of rows is same like length of list you can create new Dataframe and append by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
np.random.seed(2023)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(7, size=(7,3))).add_prefix('a')

count_x=[[7, 3, 4, 4, 2, 41, 8],
    [3, 9, 0, 8, 2, 22, 11],
      [2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 9, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
      [2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 9],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
     [3, 2, 0, 8, 1, 10, 9]]

df = df1.join(pd.DataFrame(count_x).T)
print (df)
   a0  a1  a2   0   1  2  3  4  5  6   7
0   1   6   1   7   3  2  1  2  0  0   3
1   4   3   4   3   9  1  0  0  0  0   2
2   4   6   5   4   0  0  0  0  0  0   0
3   0   6   1   4   8  0  0  1  0  0   8
4   5   5   5   2   2  2  0  2  0  0   1
5   0   2   3  41  22  9  2  0  3  2  10
6   2   4   1   8  11  1  1  9  1  0   9
```

Comment: 0 column should be filled with [7,3,4,4,2,41,8] vertically not row wise, any help on that?

Comment: @Chinmay - Can you test `df1.join(pd.DataFrame(count_x, columns=df1.index).T)`

Comment: i want to fill column index from df1.iloc[:,5:13] , i tried above code it gives me error, Shape of passed values is (7, 1), indices imply (7, 7)

Comment: @Chinmay - what is `print (pd.DataFrame(count_x).shape)` ?

Comment: i rerun the code it shows(8,7) and it gets merged at the end of the dataframe, how do i insert them at df1.iloc[:,5:13]

Comment: what is `print(df1.index)` ?

Comment: Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype='object')

Comment: @Chinmay Can you test `df1.join(pd.DataFrame(count_x).T)` ?

Comment: same issue, its joining at end of df1, why df1.iloc[:,5:5+len(count_x[0])] = count_x is now working in my case?

Comment: @Chinmay - Not understand if `print (pd.DataFrame(count_x).shape)` is `(8,7)` how possible error is `Shape of passed values is (7, 1), indices imply (7, 7)` ?

Comment: Shape of passed values is (7, 1), indices imply (7, 7) error is now cleared. that count_x dataframe is joining at the end like you edited your solution. I want to join count x at df1.iloc[:,5:13]

Comment: So need `df1.iloc[:,5:5+len(count_x)] = np.array(count_x).T` or `df1.iloc[:,5:13] = np.array(count_x).T` ?